# How to fix Installation failed due to device offline? Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Retry

Tags: android-studio-4.0

**look here figure below:**
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9j8C.png)

06/14 05:56:50: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 API 29 3.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\Ahmed\AFAQTravelTurismMobileApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'device offline'
Retry

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Users\Ahmed\AFAQTravelTurismMobileApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

- Go to the directory and (re)move `app-debug.apk`
- Remove the device from the cable.
- Connect the device again and try to run it.

Its worked for me.